# SharePoint 2013 permission for Inforpath 2013 forms developer

Tags: sharepoint, permissions, infopath

What permissions are required on SharePoint 2013 for a user to be able to create/modify form using Infopath2013

Answer (score 0):

Design and edit permissions should do it.